# What SEO problem will occur when we install WordPress on PaaS?

Tags: seo, wordpress

Openshift cloud provided by RedHat have told us to "set up a CNAME record with your DNS provider" if we need to use a custom domain in PaaS.

What SEO problem will occur when we install WordPress on PaaS?

Comment: somebody please help.

Comment: What makes you think there will be problems?

Comment: since we can only update CNAME name and not the set the name servers.. open shift provide a sub domain. And we can only use our domain as alias. What seo problem will cause when we use alias and update the .htaccess. ?

Comment: None, as long as you make sure the page can only be seen on 1 URL.

Comment: i strongly doubt since i am transferring my website to PaaS. All the links are indexed. and also ranked. But now here we use them as alias. The actual link is different. Which will be ranked? Can we control this in .htaccess?

Comment: Is the website on a domain and the blog is being set on the sub domain?

Comment: website is on a domain.. can forward or use canonical url as they suggest. But the indexing will be done for the sub domain.?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** If your DNS records are setup properly your URL links shouldn't care or know that you've switched server backends and SEO won't be affected.

All RedHat OpenShift plans come with custom domains, which is what you'll need to maintain your SEO rankings.

So long as your file structure stays the same from your previous server (or at least maps the same way) you shouldn't run into problems with SEO as the paths will not have changed.

If you don't choose to use a custom domain however, you will be forced to use OpenShift's subdomaining, and you will lose your link ranking without setting up address forwarding.

Using custom domains with OpenShift:
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way

Comment: Which domain will be indexed? the rhcloud domain or out custom domain?  What about the existing ranking? How will google index our website after the shifting?